# Reading mails from gmail account in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, pop3, gmail-pop, incoming-mail

i want to read the mails from gmail account.. i tried to login.. and was successfull.. but unable to get the mails from the inbox..
below is the code i used for logging in...

```
try
        {

            TcpClient tcpclient = new TcpClient(); // create an instance of TcpClient
            tcpclient.Connect("pop.gmail.com", 995); // HOST NAME POP SERVER and gmail uses port number 995 for POP 
            System.Net.Security.SslStream sslstream = new SslStream(tcpclient.GetStream()); // This is Secure Stream // opened the connection between client and POP Server
            sslstream.AuthenticateAsClient("pop.gmail.com"); // authenticate as client 
            //bool flag = sslstream.IsAuthenticated; // check flag 
            System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sslstream); // Asssigned the writer to stream
            System.IO.StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(sslstream); // Assigned reader to stream
            sw.WriteLine("username@gmail.com"); // refer POP rfc command, there very few around 6-9 command
            sw.Flush(); // sent to server
            sw.WriteLine("password");
            sw.Flush();
            sw.WriteLine("RETR 1"); // this will retrive your first email 
            sw.Flush();
            sw.WriteLine("Quit "); // close the connection
            sw.Flush();
            string str = string.Empty;
            string strTemp = string.Empty;
            while ((strTemp = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (strTemp == ".") // find the . character in line
                {

                    break;
                }

                if (strTemp.IndexOf("-ERR") != -1)
                {
                    break;
                }
                str += strTemp;
            }
            Response.Write(str);
            Response.Write("" + "Congratulation.. ....!!! You read your first gmail email ");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
```

can anyone please tell me how can i get the actual mails from the inbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should read server responses as soon as you issue a command.
2. You have not logged in to Gmail successfully - you should use POP3 commands like **USER**, **PASS**
3. Your code fails if email contains "-ERR" text
4. str += strTemp; is going to kill your app when you revive email with a large attachment

I'd recommend not reinventing the wheel - there are libraries for POP3 access.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at [Mail.net](http://www.lesnikowski.com/mail/), I have not had need to use it myself but I here good things about it.

Cheers